# c++ access array data of shared library

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-libraries, stm32

I am coding in stm32. Basically, I want to access a bool array data from another library. This is a header file of `AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner` library stored data in `scan.isObstacle` which is a bool array. Also I made a return function named `getObstacle()`. Another library named `AP_Tmxk_VFH` to access data from `getObstacle()`. Is that ok? Or which is the way to copy that array in `AP_Tmxk_VFH`. Thanks for your help.

**AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner**

```
class AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner {
private:
    struct{
        bool isObstacle[180] = {};  //1: unsafe; 0:safe
        bool available = false;
    }scan;
public:
    AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner();
    void init();
    void update();

    bool getAvailable() const{
        return scan.available;
    }
    bool getObstacle() const{
        return scan.isObstacle;
    }
};
```

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.h**

```
class AP_Tmxk_VFH {
private:
    struct{
        bool Certain_Value[180] = {};
    }sector;

    const AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &_lidarscanner;

public:
    // Constructor
    AP_Tmxk_VFH(const AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &_lidarscanner);
    void init();
    void update();
};
```

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.cpp**

```
AP_Tmxk_VFH::AP_Tmxk_VFH(const AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &lidarscanner) :

    _lidarscanner(lidarscanner)
    {}

void AP_Tmxk_VFH::update()
{
    if(_lidarscanner.getAvailable()){
       sector.Certain_Value = _lidarscanner.getObstacle()

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks noneworking. In function `getObstacle()` you return bool value it is not the same as array of bool.

Comment: Hope [it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_an_array.htm) can help

Answer (score 0):

Here I modfiy my code format.

**AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner.h**

```
class AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner {
    private:
        struct{
            bool isObstacle[180]= {};  //1: unsafe; 0:safe
            bool available = false;
        }scan;
    public:
        AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner();
        void init();
        void update();

        bool getAvailable() const{
            return scan.available;
        }
        void getObstacle(int (&array)[180]);
    };
```

**AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner.cpp**

```
void AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner::getObstacle(int (&array)[180])
{
for(int i=0; i<180; i++){
    if(scan.isObstacle[i]){
        array[i] = (array[i]+1 >= 5) ? 5 : array[i]+1;
    }
    else{
        array[i] = (array[i]-1 >= 0) ? array[i]-1 : 0;
    }
}
}
```

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.h**

```
class AP_Tmxk_VFH {
private:
    struct{
        int Certain_Value[180] = {};
    }sector;

    class AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &_lidarscanner;

public:
    // Constructor
    AP_Tmxk_VFH(class AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &_lidarscanner);
    void init();
    void update();
};
```

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.cpp**

```
AP_Tmxk_VFH::AP_Tmxk_VFH(class AP_Tmxk_LIDARScanner &lidarscanner) :

    _lidarscanner(lidarscanner)
    {}

void AP_Tmxk_VFH::update()
{        
      if(_lidarscanner.getAvailable()){
            _lidarscanner.getObstacle(sector.Certain_Value);
      }            

}
```